# Java: Getting a "Requires JDK 5.0 or later" error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have just installed the JDK1.8.0 32 bit version on my computer and that all seemed to work nicely. I then followed the instructions on this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400637/unable-to-find-a-javac-compiler) page to add tools.jar to the Eclipse (although, to be honest, I'm not quite sure what that means?). I'm still getting the error: `"Requires JDK 5.0 or later. Please download it from http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/".`

Could someone please help me understand what the problem is? Also, please let me know if I haven't given enough information, this is my first attempt at using Eclipse and I don't know if you need any other info.

Thanks

Mike

Comment: Check whether your project has set to use your newly downloaded JDK.

Comment: Specifically go to build path and check under libraries which Java System library is specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oracle JDK installation does not install Java in the location where Eclipse by default looks for it.

I would suggest that you go to http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp and follow instructions to get a default Java installation on your system.

Eclipse will then use that to run itself.  You can then tell Eclipse about your Java 8 JDK in Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE's and that it is to be used by default by the projects *you* write.

Note that there is not full support for the new Java 8 facilities in Eclipse yet.  That will most likely come in Eclipse 4.4 scheduled for June (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Simultaneous_Release)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I just tried what you said now, I went Windows>Preferences>Installed JRE's and edited the location to be the place where I installed the new JDK. When I try run the Build code again I get a slightly different error now, which reads "Class not found: javac1.8". Any idea what I should do about that? Thanks again!

Comment: Your installation is messed up.  Unzip a fresh copy of Eclipse and start a new workspace.

Comment: Ok great, thanks, I did that and it's working now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When you make a new project, make sure it's using the JRE you want. You may have to change it from default to "use project specific JRE", and then select the 1.8.